# Country database or droplist

Tags: html, mysql, sql, database, html-select

Does anyone have a database of all countries, but each country should be given in its own language? I found such a database but only in one language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

---

Source: https://www.technicalkeeda.com/html-tutorials/all-countries-drop-down-list-in-html

Last updated: Feb 2019

```
<select id="country" name="country">
   <option value="Afganistan">Afghanistan</option>
   <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
   <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
   <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
   <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
   <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
   <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
   <option value="Antigua & Barbuda">Antigua & Barbuda</option>
   <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
   <option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
   <option value="Aruba">Aruba</option>
   <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
   <option value="Austria">Austria</option>
   <option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
   <option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
   <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
   <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
   <option value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
   <option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
   <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
   <option value="Belize">Belize</option>
   <option value="Benin">Benin</option>
   <option value="Bermuda">Bermuda</option>
   <option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
   <option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option>
   <option value="Bonaire">Bonaire</option>
   <option value="Bosnia & Herzegovina">Bosnia & Herzegovina</option>
   <option value="Botswana">Botswana</option>
   <option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
   <option value="British Indian Ocean Ter">British Indian Ocean Ter</option>
   <option value="Brunei">Brunei</option>
   <option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
   <option value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option>
   <option value="Burundi">Burundi</option>
   <option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
   <option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option>
   <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
   <option value="Canary Islands">Canary Islands</option>
   <option value="Cape Verde">Cape Verde</option>
   <option value="Cayman Islands">Cayman Islands</option>
   <option value="Central African Republic">Central African Republic</option>
   <option value="Chad">Chad</option>
   <option value="Channel Islands">Channel Islands</option>
   <option value="Chile">Chile</option>
   <option value="China">China</option>
   <option value="Christmas Island">Christmas Island</option>
   <option value="Cocos Island">Cocos Island</option>
   <option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
   <option value="Comoros">Comoros</option>
   <option value="Congo">Congo</option>
   <option value="Cook Islands">Cook Islands</option>
   <option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
   <option value="Cote DIvoire">Cote DIvoire</option>
   <option value="Croatia">Croatia</option>
   <option value="Cuba">Cuba</option>
   <option value="Curaco">Curacao</option>
   <option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option>
   <option value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option>
   <option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
   <option value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option>
   <option value="Dominica">Dominica</option>
   <option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option>
   <option value="East Timor">East Timor</option>
   <option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>
   <option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
   <option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option>
   <option value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option>
   <option value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option>
   <option value="Estonia">Estonia</option>
   <option value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option>
   <option value="Falkland Islands">Falkland Islands</option>
   <option value="Faroe Islands">Faroe Islands</option>
   <option value="Fiji">Fiji</option>
   <option value="Finland">Finland</option>
   <option value="France">France</option>
   <option value="French Guiana">French Guiana</option>
   <option value="French Polynesia">French Polynesia</option>
   <option value="French Southern Ter">French Southern Ter</option>
   <option value="Gabon">Gabon</option>
   <option value="Gambia">Gambia</option>
   <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
   <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
   <option value="Ghana">Ghana</option>
   <option value="Gibraltar">Gibraltar</option>
   <option value="Great Britain">Great Britain</option>
   <option value="Greece">Greece</option>
   <option value="Greenland">Greenland</option>
   <option value="Grenada">Grenada</option>
   <option value="Guadeloupe">Guadeloupe</option>
   <option value="Guam">Guam</option>
   <option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option>
   <option value="Guinea">Guinea</option>
   <option value="Guyana">Guyana</option>
   <option value="Haiti">Haiti</option>
   <option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
   <option value="Honduras">Honduras</option>
   <option value="Hong Kong">Hong Kong</option>
   <option value="Hungary">Hungary</option>
   <option value="Iceland">Iceland</option>
   <option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
   <option value="India">India</option>
   <option value="Iran">Iran</option>
   <option value="Iraq">Iraq</option>
   <option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
   <option value="Isle of Man">Isle of Man</option>
   <option value="Israel">Israel</option>
   <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
   <option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option>
   <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
   <option value="Jordan">Jordan</option>
   <option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option>
   <option value="Kenya">Kenya</option>
   <option value="Kiribati">Kiribati</option>
   <option value="Korea North">Korea North</option>
   <option value="Korea Sout">Korea South</option>
   <option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option>
   <option value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option>
   <option value="Laos">Laos</option>
   <option value="Latvia">Latvia</option>
   <option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
   <option value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option>
   <option value="Liberia">Liberia</option>
   <option value="Libya">Libya</option>
   <option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option>
   <option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option>
   <option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
   <option value="Macau">Macau</option>
   <option value="Macedonia">Macedonia</option>
   <option value="Madagascar">Madagascar</option>
   <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
   <option value="Malawi">Malawi</option>
   <option value="Maldives">Maldives</option>
   <option value="Mali">Mali</option>
   <option value="Malta">Malta</option>
   <option value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option>
   <option value="Martinique">Martinique</option>
   <option value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option>
   <option value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option>
   <option value="Mayotte">Mayotte</option>
   <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
   <option value="Midway Islands">Midway Islands</option>
   <option value="Moldova">Moldova</option>
   <option value="Monaco">Monaco</option>
   <option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
   <option value="Montserrat">Montserrat</option>
   <option value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
   <option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
   <option value="Myanmar">Myanmar</option>
   <option value="Nambia">Nambia</option>
   <option value="Nauru">Nauru</option>
   <option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>
   <option value="Netherland Antilles">Netherland Antilles</option>
   <option value="Netherlands">Netherlands (Holland, Europe)</option>
   <option value="Nevis">Nevis</option>
   <option value="New Caledonia">New Caledonia</option>
   <option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
   <option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option>
   <option value="Niger">Niger</option>
   <option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
   <option value="Niue">Niue</option>
   <option value="Norfolk Island">Norfolk Island</option>
   <option value="Norway">Norway</option>
   <option value="Oman">Oman</option>
   <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
   <option value="Palau Island">Palau Island</option>
   <option value="Palestine">Palestine</option>
   <option value="Panama">Panama</option>
   <option value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option>
   <option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option>
   <option value="Peru">Peru</option>
   <option value="Phillipines">Philippines</option>
   <option value="Pitcairn Island">Pitcairn Island</option>
   <option value="Poland">Poland</option>
   <option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
   <option value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option>
   <option value="Qatar">Qatar</option>
   <option value="Republic of Montenegro">Republic of Montenegro</option>
   <option value="Republic of Serbia">Republic of Serbia</option>
   <option value="Reunion">Reunion</option>
   <option value="Romania">Romania</option>
   <option value="Russia">Russia</option>
   <option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option>
   <option value="St Barthelemy">St Barthelemy</option>
   <option value="St Eustatius">St Eustatius</option>
   <option value="St Helena">St Helena</option>
   <option value="St Kitts-Nevis">St Kitts-Nevis</option>
   <option value="St Lucia">St Lucia</option>
   <option value="St Maarten">St Maarten</option>
   <option value="St Pierre & Miquelon">St Pierre & Miquelon</option>
   <option value="St Vincent & Grenadines">St Vincent & Grenadines</option>
   <option value="Saipan">Saipan</option>
   <option value="Samoa">Samoa</option>
   <option value="Samoa American">Samoa American</option>
   <option value="San Marino">San Marino</option>
   <option value="Sao Tome & Principe">Sao Tome & Principe</option>
   <option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
   <option value="Senegal">Senegal</option>
   <option value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option>
   <option value="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</option>
   <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
   <option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option>
   <option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option>
   <option value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option>
   <option value="Somalia">Somalia</option>
   <option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
   <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
   <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
   <option value="Sudan">Sudan</option>
   <option value="Suriname">Suriname</option>
   <option value="Swaziland">Swaziland</option>
   <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
   <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
   <option value="Syria">Syria</option>
   <option value="Tahiti">Tahiti</option>
   <option value="Taiwan">Taiwan</option>
   <option value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option>
   <option value="Tanzania">Tanzania</option>
   <option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
   <option value="Togo">Togo</option>
   <option value="Tokelau">Tokelau</option>
   <option value="Tonga">Tonga</option>
   <option value="Trinidad & Tobago">Trinidad & Tobago</option>
   <option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option>
   <option value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
   <option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option>
   <option value="Turks & Caicos Is">Turks & Caicos Is</option>
   <option value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option>
   <option value="Uganda">Uganda</option>
   <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
   <option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
   <option value="United Arab Erimates">United Arab Emirates</option>
   <option value="United States of America">United States of America</option>
   <option value="Uraguay">Uruguay</option>
   <option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
   <option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>
   <option value="Vatican City State">Vatican City State</option>
   <option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option>
   <option value="Vietnam">Vietnam</option>
   <option value="Virgin Islands (Brit)">Virgin Islands (Brit)</option>
   <option value="Virgin Islands (USA)">Virgin Islands (USA)</option>
   <option value="Wake Island">Wake Island</option>
   <option value="Wallis & Futana Is">Wallis & Futana Is</option>
   <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
   <option value="Zaire">Zaire</option>
   <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
   <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
```

SQL

---

source: [I Need Countries List in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589896/i-need-countries-list-in-t-sql)

Last updated: Aug 2015

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_Countries
(
     CountryID INT
    ,CountryName VARCHAR(50)
    ,TwoCharCountryCode CHAR(2)
    ,ThreeCharCountryCode CHAR(3)    
);


INSERT INTO tbl_Countries VALUES 
(1,'Afghanistan','AF','AFG')
,(2,'Aland Islands','AX','ALA')
,(3,'Albania','AL','ALB')
,(4,'Algeria','DZ','DZA')
,(5,'American Samoa','AS','ASM')
,(6,'Andorra','AD','AND')
,(7,'Angola','AO','AGO')
,(8,'Anguilla','AI','AIA')
,(9,'Antarctica','AQ','ATA')
,(10,'Antigua and Barbuda','AG','ATG')
,(11,'Argentina','AR','ARG')
,(12,'Armenia','AM','ARM')
,(13,'Aruba','AW','ABW')
,(14,'Australia','AU','AUS')
,(15,'Austria','AT','AUT')
,(16,'Azerbaijan','AZ','AZE')
,(17,'Bahamas','BS','BHS')
,(18,'Bahrain','BH','BHR')
,(19,'Bangladesh','BD','BGD')
,(20,'Barbados','BB','BRB')
,(21,'Belarus','BY','BLR')
,(22,'Belgium','BE','BEL')
,(23,'Belize','BZ','BLZ')
,(24,'Benin','BJ','BEN')
,(25,'Bermuda','BM','BMU')
,(26,'Bhutan','BT','BTN')
,(27,'Bolivia','BO','BOL')
,(28,'Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba','BQ','BES')
,(29,'Bosnia and Herzegovina','BA','BIH')
,(30,'Botswana','BW','BWA')
,(31,'Bouvet Island','BV','BVT')
,(32,'Brazil','BR','BRA')
,(33,'British Indian Ocean Territory','IO','IOT')
,(34,'Brunei','BN','BRN')
,(35,'Bulgaria','BG','BGR')
,(36,'Burkina Faso','BF','BFA')
,(37,'Burundi','BI','BDI')
,(38,'Cambodia','KH','KHM')
,(39,'Cameroon','CM','CMR')
,(40,'Canada','CA','CAN')
,(41,'Cape Verde','CV','CPV')
,(42,'Cayman Islands','KY','CYM')
,(43,'Central African Republic','CF','CAF')
,(44,'Chad','TD','TCD')
,(45,'Chile','CL','CHL')
,(46,'China','CN','CHN')
,(47,'Christmas Island','CX','CXR')
,(48,'Cocos (Keeling) Islands','CC','CCK')
,(49,'Colombia','CO','COL')
,(50,'Comoros','KM','COM')
,(51,'Congo','CG','COG')
,(52,'Cook Islands','CK','COK')
,(53,'Costa Rica','CR','CRI')
,(54,'Ivory Coast','CI','CIV')
,(55,'Croatia','HR','HRV')
,(56,'Cuba','CU','CUB')
,(57,'Curacao','CW','CUW')
,(58,'Cyprus','CY','CYP')
,(59,'Czech Republic','CZ','CZE')
,(60,'Democratic Republic of the Congo','CD','COD')
,(61,'Denmark','DK','DNK')
,(62,'Djibouti','DJ','DJI')
,(63,'Dominica','DM','DMA')
,(64,'Dominican Republic','DO','DOM')
,(65,'Ecuador','EC','ECU')
,(66,'Egypt','EG','EGY')
,(67,'El Salvador','SV','SLV')
,(68,'Equatorial Guinea','GQ','GNQ')
,(69,'Eritrea','ER','ERI')
,(70,'Estonia','EE','EST')
,(71,'Ethiopia','ET','ETH')
,(72,'Falkland Islands (Malvinas)','FK','FLK')
,(73,'Faroe Islands','FO','FRO')
,(74,'Fiji','FJ','FJI')
,(75,'Finland','FI','FIN')
,(76,'France','FR','FRA')
,(77,'French Guiana','GF','GUF')
,(78,'French Polynesia','PF','PYF')
,(79,'French Southern Territories','TF','ATF')
,(80,'Gabon','GA','GAB')
,(81,'Gambia','GM','GMB')
,(82,'Georgia','GE','GEO')
,(83,'Germany','DE','DEU')
,(84,'Ghana','GH','GHA')
,(85,'Gibraltar','GI','GIB')
,(86,'Greece','GR','GRC')
,(87,'Greenland','GL','GRL')
,(88,'Grenada','GD','GRD')
,(89,'Guadaloupe','GP','GLP')
,(90,'Guam','GU','GUM')
,(91,'Guatemala','GT','GTM')
,(92,'Guernsey','GG','GGY')
,(93,'Guinea','GN','GIN')
,(94,'Guinea-Bissau','GW','GNB')
,(95,'Guyana','GY','GUY')
,(96,'Haiti','HT','HTI')
,(97,'Heard Island and McDonald Islands','HM','HMD')
,(98,'Honduras','HN','HND')
,(99,'Hong Kong','HK','HKG')
,(100,'Hungary','HU','HUN')
,(101,'Iceland','IS','ISL')
,(102,'India','IN','IND')
,(103,'Indonesia','ID','IDN')
,(104,'Iran','IR','IRN')
,(105,'Iraq','IQ','IRQ')
,(106,'Ireland','IE','IRL')
,(107,'Isle of Man','IM','IMN')
,(108,'Israel','IL','ISR')
,(109,'Italy','IT','ITA')
,(110,'Jamaica','JM','JAM')
,(111,'Japan','JP','JPN')
,(112,'Jersey','JE','JEY')
,(113,'Jordan','JO','JOR')
,(114,'Kazakhstan','KZ','KAZ')
,(115,'Kenya','KE','KEN')
,(116,'Kiribati','KI','KIR')
,(117,'Kosovo','XK','---')
,(118,'Kuwait','KW','KWT')
,(119,'Kyrgyzstan','KG','KGZ')
,(120,'Laos','LA','LAO')
,(121,'Latvia','LV','LVA')
,(122,'Lebanon','LB','LBN')
,(123,'Lesotho','LS','LSO')
,(124,'Liberia','LR','LBR')
,(125,'Libya','LY','LBY')
,(126,'Liechtenstein','LI','LIE')
,(127,'Lithuania','LT','LTU')
,(128,'Luxembourg','LU','LUX')
,(129,'Macao','MO','MAC')
,(130,'Macedonia','MK','MKD')
,(131,'Madagascar','MG','MDG')
,(132,'Malawi','MW','MWI')
,(133,'Malaysia','MY','MYS')
,(134,'Maldives','MV','MDV')
,(135,'Mali','ML','MLI')
,(136,'Malta','MT','MLT')
,(137,'Marshall Islands','MH','MHL')
,(138,'Martinique','MQ','MTQ')
,(139,'Mauritania','MR','MRT')
,(140,'Mauritius','MU','MUS')
,(141,'Mayotte','YT','MYT')
,(142,'Mexico','MX','MEX')
,(143,'Micronesia','FM','FSM')
,(144,'Moldava','MD','MDA')
,(145,'Monaco','MC','MCO')
,(146,'Mongolia','MN','MNG')
,(147,'Montenegro','ME','MNE')
,(148,'Montserrat','MS','MSR')
,(149,'Morocco','MA','MAR')
,(150,'Mozambique','MZ','MOZ')
,(151,'Myanmar (Burma)','MM','MMR')
,(152,'Namibia','NA','NAM')
,(153,'Nauru','NR','NRU')
,(154,'Nepal','NP','NPL')
,(155,'Netherlands','NL','NLD')
,(156,'New Caledonia','NC','NCL')
,(157,'New Zealand','NZ','NZL')
,(158,'Nicaragua','NI','NIC')
,(159,'Niger','NE','NER')
,(160,'Nigeria','NG','NGA')
,(161,'Niue','NU','NIU')
,(162,'Norfolk Island','NF','NFK')
,(163,'North Korea','KP','PRK')
,(164,'Northern Mariana Islands','MP','MNP')
,(165,'Norway','NO','NOR')
,(166,'Oman','OM','OMN')
,(167,'Pakistan','PK','PAK')
,(168,'Palau','PW','PLW')
,(169,'Palestine','PS','PSE')
,(170,'Panama','PA','PAN')
,(171,'Papua New Guinea','PG','PNG')
,(172,'Paraguay','PY','PRY')
,(173,'Peru','PE','PER')
,(174,'Phillipines','PH','PHL')
,(175,'Pitcairn','PN','PCN')
,(176,'Poland','PL','POL')
,(177,'Portugal','PT','PRT')
,(178,'Puerto Rico','PR','PRI')
,(179,'Qatar','QA','QAT')
,(180,'Reunion','RE','REU')
,(181,'Romania','RO','ROU')
,(182,'Russia','RU','RUS')
,(183,'Rwanda','RW','RWA')
,(184,'Saint Barthelemy','BL','BLM')
,(185,'Saint Helena','SH','SHN')
,(186,'Saint Kitts and Nevis','KN','KNA')
,(187,'Saint Lucia','LC','LCA')
,(188,'Saint Martin','MF','MAF')
,(189,'Saint Pierre and Miquelon','PM','SPM')
,(190,'Saint Vincent and the Grenadines','VC','VCT')
,(191,'Samoa','WS','WSM')
,(192,'San Marino','SM','SMR')
,(193,'Sao Tome and Principe','ST','STP')
,(194,'Saudi Arabia','SA','SAU')
,(195,'Senegal','SN','SEN')
,(196,'Serbia','RS','SRB')
,(197,'Seychelles','SC','SYC')
,(198,'Sierra Leone','SL','SLE')
,(199,'Singapore','SG','SGP')
,(200,'Sint Maarten','SX','SXM')
,(201,'Slovakia','SK','SVK')
,(202,'Slovenia','SI','SVN')
,(203,'Solomon Islands','SB','SLB')
,(204,'Somalia','SO','SOM')
,(205,'South Africa','ZA','ZAF')
,(206,'South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands','GS','SGS')
,(207,'South Korea','KR','KOR')
,(208,'South Sudan','SS','SSD')
,(209,'Spain','ES','ESP')
,(210,'Sri Lanka','LK','LKA')
,(211,'Sudan','SD','SDN')
,(212,'Suriname','SR','SUR')
,(213,'Svalbard and Jan Mayen','SJ','SJM')
,(214,'Swaziland','SZ','SWZ')
,(215,'Sweden','SE','SWE')
,(216,'Switzerland','CH','CHE')
,(217,'Syria','SY','SYR')
,(218,'Taiwan','TW','TWN')
,(219,'Tajikistan','TJ','TJK')
,(220,'Tanzania','TZ','TZA')
,(221,'Thailand','TH','THA')
,(222,'Timor-Leste (East Timor)','TL','TLS')
,(223,'Togo','TG','TGO')
,(224,'Tokelau','TK','TKL')
,(225,'Tonga','TO','TON')
,(226,'Trinidad and Tobago','TT','TTO')
,(227,'Tunisia','TN','TUN')
,(228,'Turkey','TR','TUR')
,(229,'Turkmenistan','TM','TKM')
,(230,'Turks and Caicos Islands','TC','TCA')
,(231,'Tuvalu','TV','TUV')
,(232,'Uganda','UG','UGA')
,(233,'Ukraine','UA','UKR')
,(234,'United Arab Emirates','AE','ARE')
,(235,'United Kingdom','GB','GBR')
,(236,'United States','US','USA')
,(237,'United States Minor Outlying Islands','UM','UMI')
,(238,'Uruguay','UY','URY')
,(239,'Uzbekistan','UZ','UZB')
,(240,'Vanuatu','VU','VUT')
,(241,'Vatican City','VA','VAT')
,(242,'Venezuela','VE','VEN')
,(243,'Vietnam','VN','VNM')
,(244,'Virgin Islands, British','VG','VGB')
,(245,'Virgin Islands, US','VI','VIR')
,(246,'Wallis and Futuna','WF','WLF')
,(247,'Western Sahara','EH','ESH')
,(248,'Yemen','YE','YEM')
,(249,'Zambia','ZM','ZMB')
,(250,'Zimbabwe','ZW','ZWE');
```